# What is the precise relation between the definition of $e$ from compound profit and the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

As in I understand the relation between compound profit and exponentiation:
20% interest after $n$ years is given by $1.2^n$
and I understand the derivations of $e$ as the limit as$ n\rightarrow \infty$ of $(1+1/n)^n$
and as the value such that $d/dx(a^x)=a^x$
I just don't understand the exact mathematical link between the two.
Is it just conincedence that the constant derived from continuous interest's exponential is equal to its derivative or is there an rigorous mathematical link between the two.

Comment: There comes a point in analysis where you want to define $e^x$.  There are several versions, two of which you give.  Another is the Taylor series $e^x=\sum \frac {x^n}{n!}$ and there is $\log x=\int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ with $e^x$ is the inverse function to $\log x$.  Each class chooses one as its definition and proves the rest as theorems.  Once this exercise is done, many people forget which is the basic one and just know them all as properties of $e^x$.  I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, we know $$e=\lim_{m\to \infty}(1+\frac1m)^m$$
Which represents the maximum (limit) amount when a bank applies an instant compound interest of 100% with an initial amount of $1$ dollar. Let $n=\frac1m$, then we have:
$$e=\lim_{n\to0}(1+n)^\frac1n$$
As $m\to \infty$, $n\to0$

Now, take the derivative of $f(x)=e^x$ by definition:

$$f^´(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^xe^h-e^x}h=e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h$$
Let $y=e^h-1 \Rightarrow h=ln(1+y)$. As $h\to0$, $y\to0$. Substituting:
$$f^´(x)=e^x\lim_{y\to0}\frac y{ln(1+y)}=e^x\lim_{y\to0}\frac 1{\frac 1y ln(1+y)}=e^x\lim_{y\to0}\frac 1{ln(1+y)^\frac 1y }=e^x\frac 1{ln\lim_{y\to0}(1+y)^\frac 1y}=e^x\frac 1{lne}=e^x$$
The exponential function is defined by the constant $e$, which comes from instant compound interest. This definition of $e$ is the reason that allows the derivative of the exponential function be the exponential function itself.

I hope this answered your question

Comment: But surely e isn't the limit as h-->0 of (1+y)^(1/y) but the limit as y-->0. Where does this switch in limits take place?

Comment: Furthermore, is there an inherent link between the two definitions that I'm missing or did it happen to work out. When Bernoulli first discovered e he had no idea that the exponential function of it was equal to its derivative, was it a shock that e came up again there or obvious- why does that property inherently mean it's equal to its own derivative?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer. When you change the variable (h to y) changes the "--->". If h=0, then y=e^0-1=0. That´s why you can change the variable in a limit (be sure to also change the "approaching")

Comment: As someone said in the comments above, it depends on how you define e. If you take the definition of e as $\lim_{m\to \infty}(1+\frac1m)^m$, then is implicit all his properties: one of them (the derivative of e^x) is shown in the answer. This proof is based on properties of the limits, logarithms and a little bit of algebra. You could also define e^x by Taylor series and prove that $e=\lim_{m\to \infty}(1+\frac1m)^m$ and all other properties